# Added prefix to django tables resulted in ProgrammingError. How can i solve it?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-forms

I have added prefix to all my tables in DB using package https://pypi.org/project/django-db-prefix/

I have made all migrations, and when I run the server its working fine.
I am not able to open any page and is showing ProgrammingError

```
 File "/home/aryan/anaconda3/envs/shiraz/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 98, in execute
return super().execute(sql, params)
File "/home/aryan/anaconda3/envs/shiraz/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 66, in execute
return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
File "/home/aryan/anaconda3/envs/shiraz/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
return executor(sql, params, many, context)
File "/home/aryan/anaconda3/envs/shiraz/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/home/aryan/anaconda3/envs/shiraz/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
File "/home/aryan/anaconda3/envs/shiraz/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "django_session" does not exist
LINE 1: ...ession_data", "django_session"."expire_date" FROM "django_se...
                                                         ^

[07/Jul/2021 05:53:37] "GET /sr_admin/signin/ HTTP/1.1" 500 181053
```

After migrations all the default tables like 'django_session', 'django_migrations', 'auth_group' etc. are also overridden, and I hope the error is because of that.

What should I do to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

If your tables are already make you can try the following :

- python manage.py migrate --fake
- python manage.py migrate --fake-initial
- python manage.py runserver

Comment: I tried dropping the DB, deleting the migrations and again migrating the DB, but results in the same error.